# ASP.NET Web API not geting json data from a remote service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-web-api

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/hosting-aspnet-web-api/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms) to build my first Asp.net Web API in a Web Form website but I am facing an issue. I have created two projects:

1. **host project** for the definition of the web service
2. **client project** to consume the web
       service.

Now my issue is that if I navigate to my web api URL using a web browser ex) `http://localhost:39930/api/products/` then this works perfectly and an XML or Json data is returned depending on the browser.

However, if I use the web service URL of the in my client website then nothing get returned!

Here is how I call the web service from my client website:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="products">
    </tbody>
</table>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function getProducts() {
         $.getJSON("http://localhost:39930/api/products",
             function (data) {
                 $('#products').empty(); // Clear the table body.

                 // Loop through the list of products.
                 $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                     // Add a table row for the product.
                     var row = '<td>' + val.Name + '</td><td>' + val.Price + '</td>';
                     $('<tr/>', { text: row })  // Append the name.
                         .appendTo($('#products'));
                 });
             });
     }

     $(document).ready(getProducts);
</script>
```

And here is a snapshot of the request in firebug:

[image]

Notice that the response is empty.

So, am I doing something wrong here? Is there some configuration that should be added to allow a service to be remotely called?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your host project and client project are running on different ports which is violating the same origin policy and its prohibited. See the details here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

If you want this to work, you can use jsonp instead of json. Have a look at this article http://www.jquery4u.com/json/jsonp-examples/#.UISVAo3iYsc

Comment: ... And here is a really good article to get this issue resolved: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/02/Creating-a-JSONP-Formatter-for-ASPNET-Web-API